# Cleanse Data on opportunity Contact Role

Tags: soql

I have inherited an org with a trigger which was creating duplicate opportunity contact roles. I have fixed the issue of the duplication but there are lot of OCR records which are duplicate. i want to cleanse to remove the duplicates.

```
SELECT count(id),opportunity.name opp,contact.name con from opportunityContactrole  group by opportunity.name,contact.name  having count(id)>2 LIMIT 2000
```

This is the query i used to take a look at the duplicates and had to restrict to 2000 as query editor on dev console wouldnt allow me to fetch more records.

The question i had was, what would be the best way to cleanse the existing OCR records? What would be query that i would need to use to get the duplicate record ids so that i can delete them using data loader? The above query would not get me the ids

Any thoughts ?

Comment: The 2000 limit isn't an editor limit, but an API limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aggregate query won't get you the Id values you need, so you basically need two queries. I find it easiest to do this all server-side, without a complicated setup; Apex code makes this pretty trivial. Here's some sample execute anonymous code that you might use to clean up the data pretty quickly:

```
while(true) {
    Set<Id> contactIds = new Set<Id>(), 
        oppIds = new Set<Id>();
    Set<OpportunityContactRole> roles = new Set<OpportunityContactRole>();
    // Find duplicates
    for(AggregateResult result:[
        SELECT ContactId cid, OpportunityId oid, COUNT(Id)
        FROM OpportunityContactRole
        GROUP BY ContactId, OpportunityId
        HAVING COUNT(Id) > 1
        LIMIT 2000
    ]) {
        Id conId = (Id)result.get('cid'), oppId = (Id)result.get('oid');
        contactIds.add(conid);
        oppIds.add(oppId);
    }
    OpportunityContactRole[] dupes = new OpportunityContactRole[0];
    Integer limitsLeft = Limits.getLimitDmlRows() - limits.getDmlRows();
    // Governor limits, lets stop now.
    if(limitsLeft == 0) {
        break;
    }
    for(OpportunityContactRole record: [
        SELECT ContactId, OpportunityId
        FROM OpportunityContactRole
        WHERE ContactId = :contactIds AND OpportunityId = :oppIds
    ]) {
        if(!roles.add(new OpportunityContactRole(ContactId=record.ContactId, OpportunityId=record.OpportunityId))) {
            // We've already seen this role
            dupes.add(record);
            // Stop if at governor limit
            if(dupes.size() == limitsLeft) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    delete dupes;
    // No more rows to process, done!
    if(dupes.isEmpty()) {
        break;
    }
}
System.assert(Limits.getQueryRows() > 0,'Nothing to do!');
```

This script cleans up to 10,000 contact roles per execution. This script also presumes no triggers or anything else that would change the limits. You may need to account for this difference in the code. Also, this code will consider the same contact on the same opportunity duplicates regardless of the "role" (e.g. Purchaser, Decision Maker); if you need this extra protection, additional work needs to be done. The general idea is to execute this code until you get an assertion "Nothing to do!". That's how you know it's done doing its work.

Comment: wow!! i didnt expect the whole code. Just a quick question what does this do ?  OpportunityContactRole[] dupes = new OpportunityContactRole[0];  how is it different from the regular list declaration?

Comment: @Prady You won't always get the full code, but this was a pretty trivial code that you're not likely to find in some random blog post or something. As far as the line in question, it's identical in behavior to using `List<...>`, but I don't like typing the longer form, because it's more typing, and also because I grew up on a history of C, where this form is how'd you'd declare and initialize an array list.

Comment: Thanks for all the help not just for this question but for all the answers you have given on here

Comment: @Prady You're welcome!